# Two models in one view in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, model, controller

I'm having trouble implementing two models in a single View.

Here are my two models:

```
    public class DoctorViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int GodineIskustva { get; set; }
    }
}

    public class PatientViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }   
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PersonalID { get; set; }
        public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is how I recieve a single model inside my View

```
@model IEnumerable<PatientViewModel>
```

I need to be able to loop through list of both doctors and patients inside my view.

My doctor service method for getting all doctors (as an exampple, same thing with patients)

```
public IEnumerable<Doctor> GetDoctors()
{
    return doctorRepository.GetAll();
}
```

And my controller class for patients (as an exampple, same thing with doctors)

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {

            List<PatientViewModel> model = new List<PatientViewModel>();
            patientService.GetUsers().ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                PatientViewModel patient = new PatientViewModel
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    PersonalID = p.PersonalID,
                    DoctorId = p.DoctorId
                };
                model.Add(patient);
            });

            return View(model);
        }
```

I have tried using tuples or a complex model class containing those two models and I could never get it to work. Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this?

My ViewModel class:

```
    public class DoctorPatientViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApp.Models.PatientViewModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'WebApp.Models.DoctorPatientViewModel'.
```

My GenericRepository class

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using ServiceLayer;
using DomainLayer.Entities;

namespace RepositoryLayer
{
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : SharedEntity
    {
        private readonly EntityContext context;
        private DbSet<T> entities;

        public GenericRepository(EntityContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            entities = context.Set<T>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return entities.AsEnumerable();
        }

        public T Get(long id)
        {
            return entities.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
        }
        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            entities.Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            entities.Remove(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
            }
            entities.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a `ViewModel` that contains properties of `List<Doctor>` and `List<PatientViewModel>`, then change your View's model binding to accept this type of ViewModel - `@model MyNewViewModel (Replace with whatever you call your view model containing the two lists)`

Comment: @RyanWilson I edited my post to show that I tried that already and what error I was getting, if you could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Change this line in your `View`: `@model IEnumerable<PatientViewModel>` to `@model DoctorPatientViewModel` and pass that type of ViewModel to your View via the `Index` method in your controller.

Comment: @RyanWilson I'm having trouble with the index function. After making a new  `List<DoctorPatientViewModel> model = new List<DoctorPatientViewModel>();` inside the Index(), how do I actually add all the doctors and patients to it? This is my first time trying out asp.net so I'm really new to it all.

Comment: You don't need a `List<DoctorPatientViewModel>`, you need a single `DoctorPatientViewModel`, populate the `Lists` of the model like you would in your examples, then pass this single model into the `return View("Index", DoctorPatientViewModel);`

Comment: `DoctorPatientViewModel viewModel = new DoctorPatientViewModel();` `viewModel.Doctors = doctorRepository.GetAll();` `patientService.GetUsers().ToList().ForEach(p =>
            {
                PatientViewModel patient = new PatientViewModel
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    FirstName = p.FirstName,
                    LastName = p.LastName,
                    PersonalID = p.PersonalID,
                    DoctorId = p.DoctorId
                };
                viewModel.Patients.Add(patient);
            });`

Comment: @RyanWilson If I try to do viewModel.Doctors = doctorRepository.GetAll(); I get `Use of unassigned local variable doctorRepository`. If I try to initilaze it I get `there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of GenericRepository<Doctor>.GenericRepository(EntityContext)` I have added how code that shows how my repository looks like

Answer (score 0):

i faced this same issue ,I got solution regarding this,Ienumerable is OK,i Have used List

now need to change in your View

```
@model 'Namespace'.'ViewModelsFolder'.DoctorPatientViewModel
```